Writing a counting process $N(t)$ as $N(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n(t)} Y_k$ : Existence and properties of $Y_k$?
Let $N(t)$ be the counting renewal process arising from interarrival times $\{X_k\}$ which are independent, identically-distributed, positive random variables, with mean $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mu$ and variance $\text{Var}(X_k) = \sigma^2$.

For $t$ a non-negative integer, can $N(t)$ be written as $N(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n(t)} Y_k$  where $\{Y_k\}$ are independent, identically-distributed, non-negative, integer-valued random variables?
If so, what are $\mathbb{E}(Y_k)$ and $\text{Var}(Y_k)$ ?  (Can it at least be proven that they are finite?)
Is it true that if $\mathbb{E}(X_k^3) < \infty$  then $\mathbb{E}(Y_k^3) < \infty$? (If not, what condition will suffice?)

Motivation: I am seeking to apply a Berry-Esseen theorem on the sum of a random number of random variables, using $N(t)$ as the number of summands. See Theorem 10.6 of Chen, Goldstein & Shao (2011).
Edit 1: Changed the summation to $\dots = \sum_{k=1}^{n(t)} \dots$ (was  $\sum_{k=1}^t$)
What I have tried. (see my erroneous attempt below)

See this paper [1] and references within: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.08672
The usual approach is to bound the probability of $\{N(t) < n\}$ using an equivalent event related to $T(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$:
$$
    \{N(t) < n\} = \{T(n) > t\}.
$$
This helps because $T(n)$ is a sum of i.i.d. variables.
I don't think you can find an easy i.i.d. sum representation for $N(t)$ unless it is a (compound) Poisson process, or a discrete-time analogue.

[1] Reinert G, Yang C. A bound on the rate of convergence in the central limit theorem for renewal processes under second moment conditions. Journal of Applied Probability. 2020;57(1):343-360. doi:10.1017/jpr.2019.101

This answer is incorrect. The error has been highlighted. I am keeping the answer here because it is useful for understanding mistaken logic.  Thanks to @Ziv for the feedback.
Construct $Y_k$ as the number of arrivals in the interval $(k-1,k]$. Then $N(t) = \sum_{k=1}^t Y_k$.

The variables $\{ Y_k \}$ are integer valued. Moreover:
a. The interarrival durations $\{ X_k \}$ are independent, so $N(t)$ has independent increments (This deduction is incorrect - See comments, and this question) Edit: I think that the sequence $\{ Y_k \}$ is strongly mixing?
b. The durations $\{ X_k \}$ are also identically distributed and independent from time, so $N(t)$ has stationary increments.
Hence $\{ Y_k \}$ are independent and identically distributed.

(deferred to below)

Indeed, $ Y_k = N(1) $ (for all $k$).  Now $\mathbb{E}(X_k) < \infty$, so for all $t$, $N(t)$ has finite moments of all orders (1, Introduction, para 39) (Mitov & Omey, Theorem 1.16). Therefore $\mathbb{E}(Y_k^3) < \infty$.


It turns out that the above is enough for what I wanted to do. However it is useful to note that if $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mu$, $\text{Var}(X_k) = \sigma^2$ then
$$
  \frac{\mathbb{E}\bigl(N(t)\bigr)}{t}
  \to
  \frac{1}{\mu}
  \quad
  \text{as $t \to \infty$}
$$
by Blackwell's Theorem (1, Renewal Limit Theorems, para 8),
and
$$
  \frac{ \text{Var}\bigl(N(t)\bigr) }{t}
  \to
  \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^3}
  \quad
  \text{as $t \to \infty$}
$$
as noted by eg Ross (2010, Equation 7.12) or developed for example by Daley & Mohan (1978, Equation 1.5).
References

"Renewal Processes". Random. https://www.randomservices.org/random/

Mitov, Kosto V.; Omey, Edward (2014). Renewal Processes. Springer Cham, Heidelberg.

Ross, Sheldon M. (2010). "Chapter 7 - Renewal Theory and Its Applications". In Introduction to Probability Models (Tenth Edition). Academic Press, Amsterdam.

Daley, D. J., Mohan, N. R. (1978, June). Asymptotic Behaviour of the Variance of Renewal Processes and Random Walks. Ann. Probab. 6(3): 516-521



I don't think $N(t)$ has independent increments in general (unless it is a Poisson process).

For instance, if $X_k$s are i.i.d. uniform on $[10, 11]$, then your $Y_k$s are dependent: $Y_n = 1$ implies $Y_{n+1} = 0$.

Thanks @Ziv … I need to think this through.
